# How do you script adb jdwp + adb forward?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to debug an Android application using command line and script tools (I've had enough of Android Studio eating my CPU).

To connect to my app, I do `adb jdwp` to get the pid and then `adb forward tcp:8700 jdwp:<pid>` to be able to connect to the app. But I'd like to script this more.

`adb jdwp` have two limitations: 1. It doesn't return, so I have to kill `adb` with ctrl-c, 2. it only lists pids. If there are more pids, there's no easy way to see which is my app.

Is there a way to get `adb jdwp` to behave: Get it to exit and to return applicationId along with the pid?

Comment: It usually helps to provide more details about your environment (like the OS/scripting language used)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example script just like Struchu's without writing to a local file

### Improvements

- It starts the app
- It gets the apps program id after starting it
- It also uses adb over wifi given that your device is starting the hotspot

  ```
   #!/bin/bash
   PACKAGE="com.example.app"
   ACTIVITY="$PACKAGE"/"$PACKAGE"".MainActivity"
   #Connect over wifi
   adb connect "$(ip r | grep default | cut -f3 -d\ )":5555
   # adb -e connect to wifi device and start activity
   adb -e shell am start -D  -n "$ACTIVITY"
   JDWP=$(adb -e shell ps | grep "$PACKAGE" | cut -f7 -d\ )
   adb forward tcp:8000 jdwp:"$JDWP"
   jdb -sourcepath app/src/main/java -attach localhost:8000
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue with the following script (which will work provided your app is launched as a last process). As a future enhancement it could be integrated with `gradle` task runner to simplify the process even more.

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBUG_PORT=7777
SOURCE_PATH=app/src/main/java

FILE=/var/tmp/andebug-$(date +%s)
adb jdwp > "$FILE" &
sleep 1
kill -9 $!
JDWP_ID=$(tail -1 "$FILE")
rm "$FILE"
adb forward tcp:$DEBUG_PORT jdwp:$JDWP_ID
jdb -sourcepath $SOURCE_PATH -attach localhost:$DEBUG_PORT
```