# The adb jdwp does not exit when complete

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I am trying to write a shell script on linux, to debug an Android application.

the command..

```
adp jdwp
```

Will list all the debuggable running processes on the Android device. The last listed on is the most recent. I want to write a bash shell script that will take that last line, and use it in a subsequent command in the script.

The problem is that adb jdwp never exits. It just sits there after running. So the rest of the shell script does not execute at all.

How can I save the last line of the adb jdwp command to a variable, if the adb jdwp command never exits?

Comment: Related: [How do you script adb jdwp + adb forward?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39485653/295004)

Answer (score 0):

## Use timeout.

```
timeout 1 adb jdwp
<now your script can continue>
```